# Need Ability to Override Default text field

Tags: views, 7, nodes

When the textfield is left blank, a default value populates. But when a value is placed into the text field, that value should show on the front end. It currently does not.

I have  admin rights to edit,view any pages. I have enabled everything for adminstartor roles under User Management->roles. Even then am unable to update a new value to that field. It is populating the default value.

Comment: Hi there, could you be more specific?  Which field on which form are you trying to edit?  Is it a configuration setting on an admin form, a node, or a form from a custom module?

Answer (score -1):

You can change the field default text in the field settings page of the content type, for example:

admin/structure/types/manage/[your-content-type]/fields/[your-field]

You need to change [your-content-type] and [your-field] by the real values on your drupal website.

Comment: This does not answer the question. He does not want to change the default. He wants to figure out why data he enters is not saved in the database.

Comment: Maybe the question is not well explained and the title says "Override the default text field" so I am answering that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Explanation of my quest:- A content type has a text field eg:-phone number the author is different for this content type. I want to edit the phone number field with my values. But when i give Eg:888(234) . It isn't taking my number, it s taking the default number which the author has. But i have admin rights for editing the fields but when i save it and see that content type am not able to see my number which i gave.

Comment: It's really weird. Do you have enabled content revisions or other modules related with content workflow?

Comment: Hey i got it worked!. A small code change fixed this issue. I was unable to override my default value. So handled it by taking the values directly from DB when i enter it in front end!

Comment: <?php print $node->default_phone[0]['value']; ?>